# how to display the answer of a sum as a text instead of an input field

Tags: html, forms, function, sum

I try to present the result of a sum as a text instead of in an input field why is this not working with < span id="result">< /span> ? (without space)
I hope someone can help me

this is my working code only here is the answer in an input field:

```html
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="getal1">getal1 * </label>
    <select id="getal1" name="getal1" class="form-control required" onchange="sum()">
      <option value="">Kies formaat</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
      <option value='6'>6</option>  
    </select>
 </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="getal2">getal2 * </label>
    <select id="getal2" name="getal2" class="form-control required" onchange="sum()">
      <option value="">Kies formaat</option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>  
    </select>
 </div>
 
 
<div class="form-group">

<input type="text" id="result" name="result" class="form-control required">
                          </div>
 
 <script>
     function sum()
     {

        var number1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
        var number2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value;

        if (number1 == '') {
           number1 = 0
           var num3 = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
           document.getElementById('result').value = num3;
        }
        else if(number2 == '')
        {
           number2 = 0;
           var num3 = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
           document.getElementById('result').value = num3;
        }
        else
        {
           var num3 = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
           document.getElementById('result').value = num3;
        }

     }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use use this `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML` instead of `document.getElementById('result').value` it will work.

```html
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="getal1">getal1 * </label>
    <select id="getal1" name="getal1" class="form-control required" onchange="sum()">
      <option value="">Kies formaat</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
      <option value='6'>6</option>  
    </select>
 </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="getal2">getal2 * </label>
    <select id="getal2" name="getal2" class="form-control required" onchange="sum()">
      <option value="">Kies formaat</option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>  
    </select>
 </div>
 
 
<div class="form-group">

<span id="result"></span>
                          </div>
 
 <script>
     function sum()
     {

        var number1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
        var number2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value;

        if (number1 == '') {
           number1 = 0
           var num3 = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = num3;
        }
        else if(number2 == '')
        {
           number2 = 0;
           var num3 = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = num3;
        }
        else
        {
           var num3 = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = num3;
        }

     }
  </script>
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying all now i understand why it did not work

Comment: Hey @joostendarp , You have to click on the light green mark under the the upvote and downvote arrows on the left of my answer to make acceptable  :D

Answer (score 1):

Because **`span` have not property `value`**.
For non-form elements use `innerHTML`

```
// Your code .....

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = num3;
```

Also you can optimize your function

```
function sum() {

    var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('getal1').value) || 0;
    var number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('getal2').value) || 0;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = number1 + number2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="getal1">getal1 * </label>
    <select id="getal1" name="getal1" class="form-control required" onchange="sum()">
      <option value="">Kies formaat</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>
      <option value='6'>6</option>  
    </select>
 </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="getal2">getal2 * </label>
    <select id="getal2" name="getal2" class="form-control required" onchange="sum()">
      <option value="">Kies formaat</option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value='5'>5</option>  
    </select>
 </div>
 
 
<div class="form-group">

Result:<span id="result" name="result">0
                          </span>
 
 <script>
     function sum()
     {

        var number1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
        var number2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value;

        if (number1 == '') {
           number1 = 0
           var num3 = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = num3;
        }
        else if(number2 == '')
        {
           number2 = 0;
           var num3 = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML  = num3;
        }
        else
        {
           var num3 = parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2);
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML  = num3;
        }

     }
  </script>
```

Please check the above  snippet.